# Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x00 0x00)

Tags: shotwell

Hi i have moved jpg images from a SD card to a flash drive for back up and now not one pic will open, only displaying the above title message. I have looked online and tried gimp, shotwell and image viewer, tried re naming but all to no avail. So i am wondering if there is anybody who may have a solution to this problem, i did see something about deleting bytes from the file name but to be honest im not that technically minded , im old ,any help please explain for a dummy. Much appreciated as these pics are from my time with medecin sans frontieres....cheers

Comment: Do you still have them on the SD card?

Comment: no , i stupidly moved them , not copied

Comment: It looks like they may be corrupted. You could always try moving them back onto the SD or onto your hard drive to see if the work then. I doubt it, though.

Comment: i tried to move them back but the same message popped up, other pics from the same camera have worked just fine,

Comment: Can you attach/link to a couple? I want to see if I can open them on Windows and my Ubuntu. If not, they're corrupted.